# Calculating tensorflow gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, calculus

I am confused by the example in the [tensorflow gradient documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) for computing the gradient.

```
a = tf.constant(0.)
b = 2 * a
g = tf.gradients(a + b, [a, b])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(g))
```

which gives `[3.0, 1.0]`

I feel like I am really missing something obvious but if `a` is essentially `0` then `b` and therefore `a+b =0` . So how does differentiating zero with respect to a and b give you something like `[3.0, 1.0]`.

I believe I am misunderstanding tensorflows structure/syntax here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparison, consider the real-valued function *f* : **R** → **R** of one real variable, given by *f*(*x*) = 10 *x*. Here, *f*'(*x*) = 10, regardless of the value of *x*, so in particular *f*'(0) = 10.

Similarly, as explained in the tutorial, more or less by definition, the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of (*a*, *b*) ↦ *a* + *b* for *b*(*a*) = 2 *a* is (3, 1), which is independent of *a*.

For a less trivial example, let us consider

```
a = tf.constant(5.)
b = 2 * a
g = tf.gradients(a**3 + 2*b**2, [a, b])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(g))
```

Here, the total derivative with respect to *a* is the derivative of *a* ↦ *a*³ + 2(2 *a*)² = *a*³ + 8 *a*² which becomes *a* ↦ 3 *a*² + 16 *a*, while the derivative with respect to *b* is *a* ↦  4 *b*(*a*) = 8 *a*. Thus, at *a* = 5, we expect the result to be (3 · 5² + 16 · 5, 8 · 5) = (155, 40), and running the code that's exactly what you get.

Comment: I get that. Then does it make a difference really if I change `a = tf.constant(0.)` to `a = tf.constant(1.)` or any other number? It seems a bit useless to have to define `a` as a constant with a particular value since it's really just a variable and the gradient is independent of the value of the constant

Comment: You can run the code with the value of `a` changed and indeed you'll find that `sess.run(g)` is unchanged. If you want an example for which the value of `a` does matter, try `g = tf.gradients(a**2 + b, [a, b])` instead.

Comment: Could you add the comment you made into your answer as your example cleared a major misconception I had with the tf syntax

Comment: Sure, why not. I added a slightly less trivial example.

Answer (score 1):

The document describes that the notation you wrote computes the total derivative. You have 2 variables to compute the derivatives: `a` and `b`. So for the derivative for `a`, the derivative of function `a+b = a + 2a = 3a` w.r.t `a` which is 3. For `b`, the derivative of `a+b` w.r.t `b` which is 1.  `tf.constant(0.)` means you declared `a` as a constant value. What you may be thinking will happen if you declared `a` as a `tf.variable` instead.